# regex to select all URL by certain pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regex for selecting all characters and words between the two ("...") in all tags, by certain pattern for example select which starts from `/desktop/content`.

I'm sure this is fairly simple but couldn't make it on my own, can someone help?

Example:

```
<img src="/desktop/content/img/illustrations/small-flower2.svg" width="138"/>
```

selected part should be: `/desktop/content/img/illustrations/small-flower2.svg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean a regex like `/"someQuotedString([^"]*)"/gm` ?

```js
var str = '<img src="/desktop/content/img/illustrations/small-flower2.svg" width="138"/>';

console.dir(str.match(/"\/desktop\/content([^"]*)"/gm));
console.log(str.match(/"\/desktop\/content([^"]*)"/gm)[0]);
```

https://regex101.com/r/ahjdCZ/1

...if you really want to make sure it's an `<img`... tag you could also:

```
/(?!<img.*)"([^"]+)"/
```

or within any `< >` tag:

```
/<.*"(\/desktop\/content[^"]+)".*>/
```